# HMV gift vouchers bought on a credit card. Can I claim them back from my cc company?

Tags: credit-card, united-kingdom

I gave someone some HMV vouchers for Christmas and now HMV isn't accepting vouchers. Could I claim the value of these back from my credit card company under the terms of the consumer credit act?

Answer (score 1):

United Kingdom

Looks like there is some hope under the consumer credit act ...
http://www.guardian.co.uk/money/2012/jan/20/section-75-chargeback